# mouse cursor on ubuntu server minimal install

Tags: server, cursor

I've a minimal Ubuntu 18.04.4 server installation. I want to integrate a mouse cursor minimally. Features that I intend to support are:

1. Jumping to `kth` field of `ncurses` TUI form.
2. Click on `ncurses` button.

Answer (score 1):

There special package for this purpose. It is named General Purpose Mouse ([`gpm`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gpm)) interface. Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-add-repository universe

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gpm
```

Also for ncurses-based apps do not forget to use <kbd>Tab</kbd> for switching between interface elements.